# .NET Core MVC/Azure AD - 302 Found when making an ajax request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD along with asp.net core mvc. The following code is the same with a default MVC project generated with Work or School Accounts authentication.

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});    
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
})
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Everything works just fine for the most time. The app is basically a notepad. A user logs in and adds notes/tasks. Everything after logging in is done using ajax requests. After some time the app stops working because there is a need for authentication again. Note that if I refresh the page everything is working again.

[image]

Am I doing this right? Am I missing something or this kind of use case is not supported.

Should I just create a javascript function that will auto refresh the page after some time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution by accident. My goal was to hit a check endpoint every minute and If I get a 302 status code I would redirect the user to the authentication page.

```
public IActionResult Check()
{
    return Ok(new { });
}
```

I left the developer tools open and noticed that every 30 mins I get a bigger response.

[image]

And this actually refreshes the cookie and as a result there is no need to redirect the user.

So to sum up someone needs to do this check every 40-50 minutes because the expiration is set to ~1 hour by default.

Comment: did you use Ajax to make the request?

Comment: @AndrewE Yes, I did. I might be a bit late though.

Comment: Is there any other better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I just create a javascript function that will auto refresh the page after some time?

You could try to create a hidden iframe in all the templates used by the Web App to **make automatic calls to a MVC controller** method that forces a call to **renew the authentication data** on a regular basis.

This is achieved very easily by configuring an automatic javascript process in the front-end executed in a loop on a regular basis of 45'. This value could be configured or extracted from a configuration file too. The only key condition is that it must be less than one hour.

Here is the simplified example code related to MVC Controller:

```
/* Action method, inside "Account" controller class, to force renewal of user authentication session */
public void ForceSignIn() 
{
   HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, 
   OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType); 
}
```

And here is the simplified example HTML and javascript code employed to call silently in a hidden iframe to MVC Controller:

```
<iframe id="renewSession" hidden></iframe> 
 <script> 
     setInterval( function () 
         { @if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
                 <text> 
                 var renewUrl = "/Account/ForceSignIn"; 
                 var element = document.getElementById("renewSession"); 
                element.src = renewUrl; 
                 </text> 
             }
         }, 
         1000*60*45
       );
   </script>
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](http://jamuro-blog.azurewebsites.net/post/managing-azure-ad-sessions-and-ajax-calls-in-aspnet-mvc-apps-with-open-id-connect-authentication) which get the similar situation with you.

Comment: I may have found a simpler solution. Check my answer.

Comment: Glad to see that! Cheers.